# Move FrameLayout up when keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, keyboard, android-keypad

I saw similar topics but solutions I saw there won't works for me.

So I have main ConstraintLayout with some editText. On the bottom of that Constraint I have FrameLayout with 2 buttons. Problem is that when we click on editText keyboard appears and cover my FrameLayout and I want to move that FrameLayout above that keyboard (if its shown)

FrameLayout code:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:text="Continue" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I tried with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` but that doesn't work. The only thing that works somehow is adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` but that's also not great because adding this line changes height of my FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I reached what I want using `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

The point is that if I add that to main layout it changed it heights and it has own background so I cannot use that. But I remove background of that FrameLayout add inside of it simple `View` with proper height and add background on it and now it works.